# Select statement that will return one record based on multiple records

Tags: sql, sql-server, group-by, count, having-clause

Have seen similar questions but not exactly the same. I have a table with multiple ID's and want to do a select statement that fits all the PIDs and return the ID **once**.

```
+----+-----+-----+-------+
| ID | PID | DET | DETOP |
+----+-----+-----+-------+
|  1 | 123 | TR  | EQ    |
|  1 | 234 | US  | EQ    |
|  1 | 536 | L   | EQ    |
|  2 | 123 | TR  | EQ    |
|  2 | 234 | US  | EQ    |
|  2 | 536 | D   | EQ    |
+----+-----+-----+-------+
```

In other words, if 123=TR and 234=US and 536=L (hope this makes sense) return 1 and not 1,1,1.

I can't do a

```
SELECT ID 
FROM MYTABLE 
WHERE PID = 123 
  AND DET = 'TR' 
  AND PID = 234 
  AND DET = 'US' 
  AND PID = 536 
  AND DET = 'L'
```

As that will just return zero results. What would be the best approach for this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you want a `HAVING`?

```sql
SELECT ID
FROM dbo.YourTable
GROUP BY ID
HAVING COUNT(CASE WHEN PID = 123 AND DET = 'TR' THEN 1 END) > 0
   AND COUNT(CASE WHEN PID = 243 AND DET = 'US' THEN 1 END) > 0
   AND COUNT(CASE WHEN PID = 536 AND DET = 'L' THEN 1 END) > 0;
```

Comment: Thanks  - totally overlooked this. Sometimes it's good to have a second pair of eyes to look at it.

Answer (score 2):

You can use aggregation and `having`. Assuming no duplicate `(id, pid, det)`, you would phrase this as:

```
select id
from mytable
where 
    (pid = 123 and det = 'TR') 
    or (pid = 234 and det = 'US') 
    or (pid = 536 and det = 'L')
group by id
having count(*) = 3
```

Answer (score 2):

It is a classical case of relational division. The solution is :

```
CREATE TABLE MYTABLE (ID  INT,
                      PID INT , 
                      DET CHAR(3),
                      DETOP  CHAR(2),
                      PRIMARY KEY (ID, PID));
GO
INSERT INTO MYTABLE VALUES
(1,     123,   'TR',     'EQ'),
(1,     234,   'US',     'EQ'),
(1,     536,   'L ',     'EQ'),
(2,     123,   'TR',     'EQ'),
(2,     234,   'US',     'EQ'),
(2,     536,   'D ',     'EQ');
```

For the data test.

Query to solve it:

```
WITH 
DATASET AS
(SELECT * 
 FROM (VALUES (123, 'TR'), 
              (234, 'US'), 
              (536, 'L')) 
       T(PID, DET))
SELECT M.ID
FROM   DATASET AS D
       JOIN MYTABLE AS M
          ON D.PID = M.PID AND D.DET = M.DET
GROUP  BY M.ID
HAVING COUNT(*) = (SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT PID) 
                   FROM   DATASET)
```